# Data Extension and Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a conceptual question. While creating a data extension, the wizard asks how we want to link it with the Subscribers. It gives only 2 options - SubscriberKey and SubscriberID

Is there a way we can have more fields to link here?

My subscriberkey is a different value altogether and I cannot link the data extension on this.

What are the options I have here?

Please advise

Comment: Any suggestions experts?

Comment: Hi Maneesh, What are you using as your SubscriberKey and what's the value in your sendable DE that you're using to identify the subscriber?

Comment: Hello Macca, my SubscriberKey is of the format - 
'XXX-MKT-XX-emailaddress' 
The data extension has a unique field called CustomerID

I want to link this data extension with another field on the Subscribers List (CustomerID)

Comment: For a Sendable DE with SubscriberKey enabled in your account, you need SubscriberKey or SubscriberID in your DE. If you have other ways of joining keys, use a query activity to insert to a Sendable DE that follows these rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to identify which Subscriber record is going to be used, either the SubscriberID (Marketing Cloud Generated numeric unique ID) or the SubscriberKey (User specified string unique identifier) has to be mapped to a field in a Data Extension that contains that value.

It is not possible to map to a custom profile attribute (ie CustomerID) because there is no constraint for uniqueness on this field so multiple Subscriber records could have the same CustomerID so if that CustomerID was found in a DE, it wouldn't have a way to know which record to use.